# ubuntu hibernate enabling by increasing swap size

Tags: hibernate, ubuntu, swap

I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I am having an issue with hibernation - mainly when i left my laptop on with many tabs on browser open and pycharm is on after a while it does not open up. The screen freezes. I created an issue on lenovo forum but could not find a proper solution.
I read an article [how to enable hibernation on ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) now I want to do step by step what is described in article. But my question is : if I upgrade my swap from 2GB to 8GB will my MemoryRam also decrease from 14GB to 8GB?
If I understood right, issue was due to my swap size was 2GB.